# Get items inside and javascript array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, multi-select

I have this under my reducer in react. and when I

```
console.log( this.props.reducer.OEMTypes)

OEMTypes: Array(2)
    0:
    id: "11112"
    car_id: "867"
    store_id: "DEMO04"
    car_type: "FD"
    car_type_category_id: "58"
    car_type_category: "ACP"
    label: "FD"
    unassigned: false
    __proto__: Object
```

I am passing this as a prop to my multi-select field in React.

```
<Col xs={3}>
       <MultiSelect
        name="car_brands"
        isLoading={this.props.reducer.loading}
        selectAllLabel={"Select All"}
        selected={this.props.values.oem_brands}
        options={this.props.reducer.CARTypes}
         onSelectedChanged={this.handleCARSelect}
```

When I render my field, this gets rendered

```
label: "FD"
```

I want to be able to render the

```
car_type_category: "ACP"
```

Whats the best way to achieve this?

Comment: It's an array, so probably by using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to loop over each element and return the object key you want. Or by using the index if you only want one. Your problem isn't very clear.

Comment: You should check console.log what's getting to the reducer.